# Why compiling GTK (gi-gtk) application with haskell/stack is not reproducible?

Tags: haskell, gtk, haskell-stack

I have created an app that uses GTK via gi-gtk in Haskell, dependencies managed with stack (lts-9.2). I compiled it successfully on Fedora 26. Then I have successfully executed the binary on other Linux distributions as well.

After a while I wanted to compile the same application on other system (elementary OS). I cloned the repository, called `stack setup` in the project directory and then `stack build`. It complained about some missing dependencies so I installed them and finally, I got an error from GHC about my own code:

```
Not in scope: 'GTK.popoverPopdown'
Perhaps you meant one of these:
  'GTK.popoverModal' (imported from GI.Gtk)
  'GTK.popoverPosition' (imported from GI.Gtk)
Module 'GI.Gtk' does not export 'popoverPopdown'.
```

Why? As I look at the documentation (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.17/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Popover.html) there is `popoverPopdown` but nothing like `popoverModal` or `popoverPosition`.

Then I switched to another machine with another Linux distribution (Ubuntu Studio) and got the same error. Finally I took a machine with Fedora 27, did the same and got another error (also inside my app code):

```
Couldn't match expected type 'Maybe b1'
            with actual type 'GTK.Image'
In the second argument of 'GTK.buttonSetImage', namely 'icon'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: btn `GTK.buttonSetImage` icon
```

Again the documentation (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.17/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Button.html#g:26) claims something different than GHC. Could somebody explain to me what's going on?

Answering to one of the comments:
Below are what GTK versions are installed in the mentioned systems. Nonetheless GHC complains about Haskell code and I thought all the Haskell code is downloaded from Stackage. Are any dependencies generated locally on my system during `stack build`?

- Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS: libgtk2.0-0 v2.24.30, libgtk-3-0 v3.18.9
- elementary OS: libgtk2.0-0 v2.24.30, libgtk-3-0 v3.18.9
- Fedora 26: gtk2 v2.24.31, gtk3 v3.22.21
- Fedora 27: gtk2 v2.24.32, gtk3 v3.22.26

Comment: gi-gtk isn't on Stackage. Perhaps your different machines are choosing a different version from Hackage, or whatever source you are using for gi-gtk.

Comment: Isn't? https://www.stackage.org/package/gi-gtk

Comment: Now I've found that in gi-gtk v3.0.18 the signature of `buttonSetImage` was changed. But `stack list-dependencies` returns `gi-gtk 3.0.17`.

Comment: Do the GTK versions differ between these systems?

Comment: @AdamGłowacki Okay, I was imprecise: it is on Stackage, but is not in LTS-9.2.

Comment: @AdamGłowacki According to the Stackage page you linked to, the latest LTS with *gi-gtk* is 9.21, and the version of the package in it is 9.21.

Comment: @DanielWagner if I understand it correctly, LTS-9.2 does contain gi-gtk v3.0.17: https://www.stackage.org/package/gi-gtk/snapshots.

Comment: @AdamGłowacki Ah, seems you're right and I misinterpreted [this search result](https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.2/hoogle?q=gi-gtk). The big "Hoogle" title at the top should have tipped me off that the search had not done what I thought it had.

Comment: (In my previous comment, "and the version of the package in it is 9.21" should have been "and the version of the package in it is 3.0.18".)

Comment: @duplode Ok but what's the point?

Comment: @AdamGłowacki The point was that there seemed to be some confusion about the involved versions of LTS and *gi-gtk*. That's moot now, as it turned out the cause of your problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I can see that (contrary to what I had thought before) Haskell-GTK bindings **are** generated on my computer, during building `gi-gtk` package. Indeed in GTK v3.18 there was nothing like `gtk_popover_popdown`, that's why Haskell function `popoverPopdown` was not generated at all. And I guess that it's similar with `gtk_button_set_image`.

Now I need to remember that this Stackage/Hackage package is *of a different kind*. I must track the precise version of GTK I am building my application with and not rely on `stack` in this matter.